# Can a Pokémon escape while I'm trying to capture it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I found an Abra couple hour ago and I was so stressed about he could teleport away from the encounter. Hopefully I got it at the first throw.

Now I'm asking myself, as so much features of precedent Pokémon versions are not yet in Pokémon Go, can a Pokémon really escape/fly/teleport away from an encounter? If so, what trigger the escape?

Comment: While I don't have enough info for a real answer, [this article](http://venturebeat.com/2016/06/10/how-pokemon-go-brings-the-pocket-monsters-to-your-neighborhood/view-all) explicitly mentions that Abra can teleport away from battle. There's also [this GameFAQs thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/73984537) where people seem to be having an issue with Pokémon fleeing too often (though it doesn't seem like a very reliable source).

Comment: @pushasha from what I have seen and read, there is only one particular case where pokemon "escape". Are you sure they do not mean to say that Abra *teleports* when it escapes in the normal way, as opposed to other pokemon, that seem to simply run off?

Comment: @Timelord64 I am not sure, which is why I did not post it as an answer. Just thought I would share the potentially-relevant info I had found, in case it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pokémon can escape from battle, but only after a set amount of failed catch attempts. At current, there is no information on how this amount is determined, nor if it is based off the CP strength or rarity of the Pokémon.

That said, it would most definitely be influenced by the catching difficulty. You can also increase the chances of catching a Pokémon in several ways:

- Using a berry from your backpack
- Using a more powerful pokéball
- Ensuring the circle that appears over the pokémon when you hold down on the pokéball is at its smallest size, when you throw it.

For more information on the "catching circle", in regards to catching difficulty and chance, [see our question on "What does the size of the multi-coloured circle mean?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272918/what-does-the-size-of-the-multicoloured-circle-mean).

Comment: Where do you get better pokeballs from? I'm only a level 6 but the only pokeballs I keep getting are the regular ones.

Comment: Already seen pokémon with low CP (~200) escape after 1 try :( . i'm wondering if the despawn  timer may have a role on the escape

Comment: pokemon have a base catch and flee rate, your level also factors in. catch and flee rate as well as chances to catch pokemon at their base rates have been posted on various sites (mostly reddit)