# What are the exact percentage numbers for the different "catch colors" in Pokémon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you encounter a Pokémon, there's a coloured circle around it that goes from wide to narrow and so on.

I know that when the circle is green it is "easy" to catch that Pokémon, yellow is "less easy", orange is "kinda difficult" and red is "hard as hell", but does anybody know the exact percentage numbers for these colors? For example: green is over 80% chance of catching, yellow is between 60-80... something like this.

Do we have these kind of data?

Related, but not duplicate: [What does the size of the multicoloured circle mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272918/what-does-the-size-of-the-multicoloured-circle-mean)

Comment: It isn't a simple list of "color = chance to catch" but rather a spectrum of colors going from green to red as you obviously know already. I'm sure someone might be able to data-mine exact(ish) numbers but it still wouldn't help much since you can't do anything about it except hope you're lucky.

Comment: Yes, I know you can't do anything about it, it is just something I'm curious about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/pokeball/), it says that:

- Green = 100%
- Yellow = 65%
- Orange = 35%
- Red = 25%

Of course, almost no ring is strictly one color, but rather a blend between two of them. For instance, if every greenish target ring was labeled as *solely* green, you'd catch *every* single Pokemon with that color ring, but this is not the case. This simply means that the closer the ring is to pure green, then the closer the base capture rate is to 100%, and the same can be about the other colors.

In addition, these values can move around based on a few other factors, like your throw accuracy, the use of Razz Berries, what kind of ball you are using, etc. You can think of these as just baseline figures.

Comment: The color of the circle changes when you use a razzberry or change balls. The color of the circle indicates catch chance after all modifiers.

Answer (score -1):

It's different % based on what are you trying to catch.

Overall, the capture rate is denoted by the circle, but the color of the circle and the capture rate depends on the Pokemon species and CP.

Each Pokemon has a BaseCaptureRate attached to it: [source](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-capture-rate-chart/)

As you can see, the evolved versions are quite more difficult to capture than base versions. Also, different species have different percentages. Remember, a green circle is only a green circle for that Pokemon and that capture encounter. It's relative, not absolute.

Also, the items you use during capture (Berry and different kind of Pokeballs) influence the capture rate. But you know that already.

Comment: Yes, I know what influences the colour of the circle. My question is about what numbers those colours represent. Thank you for that link, though!